# How to rename mutiple images using .bat file with some conditions?

Tags: batch, rename, batch-rename

In my example i have two files the names are
test_20554783jsd.jpg
test_1_2021848ing.jpg

I need to rename these files after underscore("_")and i want the names likes
test.jpg
test_1.jpg

Already i have code

```
    @echo off
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B *_* 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=_ " %%J in ("%%~nI") do ren "%%I" "%%J%%~xI"
    )
```

but the problem is it remove underscore("_") from beginning. I dont need this because some of the file names contains undersore. so i need to remove all the letters after underscore including underscore form th last.

Can anyone optimize my code
thanks,

Comment: Use powershell instead

Answer (score 0):

Though it does not directly answer your question. But, you may use PowerShell for that because it supports using regular expression too.

I used following to achieve this:

`Get-ChildItem . -file -Filter "*_*.jpg" | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name -replace "_[^_]+$", ".jpg"}`

Comment: To not unneccessarily try to rename **all** files, you should gci only files containing an underscore.